Spanish train pre-ordered meals and special diets
On some Spanish trains it is possible to pre-order a meal.  The booking dialogue looks like this:

Clicking through them, the alternatives costing €15,50 appear to be full meals, whereas the cheaper options are snacks or sandwiches.
Is it possible to pre-order a meal with a dietary restriction, such as vegetarian or vegan?

According to RENFE, the Gasol Foundation and Sweet boxes are (lacto-ovo) vegetarian but none of the boxes are vegan. (Of course, this is all subject to change on short notice and you should check for updates before your planned travel.) Those options and some of the others do not contain pork and so may be suitable for halal travelers. There do not appear to be any other special diets catered for in this set of options.
If you are traveling on the AVE high-speed service, some classes of ticket include a premium meal, and some other classes offer the option to buy one. In such cases RENFE says that they can offer these choices with 12 hours' notice: children, strict vegetarian, ovo-lacto vegetarian, gluten-free, lactose-free, Kosher, Halal, low-salt, meat-free and low-sugar. The ability to book such a meal is presented within the booking flow when attempting to purchase a ticket in premium class on a train where it is offered:



step 1
step 2









Otherwise, there appear to be a few options meeting most diets available for purchase in the train's cafe car, or you can certainly buy other food before your trip and take it on board with you.

Hmm, unfortunately the link does not clearly state how to request a special meal.

In that case, presumably you need to call them.
